# Xcode + bitbucket - Uncommitted Changes

Tags: ios, xcode, push, commit, bitbucket

I have had a project I've been working on for a while and just added my bitbucket remote repository so I can start having a remote source control.

When I go to File -> Source Control -> Push... it always says I have uncommitted changes.

I have selected my project and done File -> Source Control -> Commit

I dont understand why it wont let me push?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of your project's user data which contains your editing context. Those files changes while using Xcode.

Stop tracking everything bellow following folders inside your project's package

- yourproject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
- yourproject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata

For information, yourproject.xcodeproj is a package, if you right click it and click "Show Package Contents" you will see mentioned directories.

And then add all files bellow those folders to ignore (**.gitignore** if you are using git)
Your .gitignore file will contains those 2 lines:
yourproject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
yourproject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata

Hope it helps

Comment: I do not have those folders.  I am using the default git within xcode.  So i just create a file within my root that is myfile.gitignore and list the files?>

Comment: I created a myproject.gitignore file in TextEdit and dropped it in my main project folder but it didnt seem to do anything.